# manipulating more than 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 6 different dataframes and I would like to append one after the other .

The only way I find to do so is append 2 each time, although I believe there must be a more efficient way to do this .

I am also looking forward after that to change the index and header names, that I also know how to do one by one, but I also believe  there must also be an efficient way to do so.

The last problem I am facing is how to set an index with with the column that is NaN , how shall I refer to it in order to set_index?

```
df1

                      NaN     1      2      3
                   1   A   17.03   13.41  19.61
                   7   B   3.42    1.51    5.44
                   8   C   5.65    2.81    1.89
df2
                      NaN     1      2      3
                    1  J   1.60   2.65   1.44
                    5  H   26.78  27.04  21.06 
df3
                      NaN    1      2      3
                   1   L   1.20   1.41   2.04
                   2   M   1.23   1.72   2.47
                   4   R  66.13  51.49  16.62
                   5   F     --  46.89  22.35
df4
                      NaN    1      2      3
                   1   A   17.03   13.41  19.61
                   7   B   3.42    1.51    5.44
                   8   C   5.65    2.81    1.89
df5
                      NaN    1      2      3
                    1  J   1.60   2.65   1.44
                    5  H   26.78  27.04  21.06 
df6
                      NaN    1      2      3
                   1   L   1.20   1.41   2.04
                   2   M   1.23   1.72   2.47
                   4   R  66.13  51.49  16.62
                   5   F     --  46.89  22.35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), for select `NaN` column is possible use `df.columns[0]` with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and `list comprehension`:

```
dfs = [df1,df2, df3, ...]
df = pd.concat([df.set_index(df.columns[0], append=True) for df in dfs])
print (df)
           1      2      3
  NaN                     
1 A    17.03  13.41  19.61
7 B     3.42   1.51   5.44
8 C     5.65   2.81   1.89
1 J      1.6   2.65   1.44
5 H    26.78  27.04  21.06
1 L     1.20   1.41   2.04
2 M     1.23   1.72   2.47
4 R    66.13  51.49  16.62
5 F       --  46.89  22.35
```

EDIT:

It seems `NaN` values can be strings:

```
print (df3.columns)
Index(['NaN', '1', '2', '3'], dtype='object')

dfs = [df1,df2, df3]
df = pd.concat([df.set_index('NaN', append=True) for df in dfs])
print (df)
           1      2      3
  NaN                     
1 A    17.03  13.41  19.61
7 B     3.42   1.51   5.44
8 C     5.65   2.81   1.89
1 J      1.6   2.65   1.44
5 H    26.78  27.04  21.06
1 L     1.20   1.41   2.04
2 M     1.23   1.72   2.47
4 R    66.13  51.49  16.62
5 F       --  46.89  22.35
```

Or if there are `np.nan` for me works also:

```
#converting to `NaN` if necessary
#df1.columns  = df1.columns.astype(float)
#df2.columns  = df2.columns.astype(float)
#df3.columns  = df3.columns.astype(float)

dfs = [df1,df2, df3]
df = pd.concat([df.set_index(np.nan, append=True) for df in dfs])
print (df)
         1.0    2.0    3.0
  nan                     
1 A    17.03  13.41  19.61
7 B     3.42   1.51   5.44
8 C     5.65   2.81   1.89
1 J      1.6   2.65   1.44
5 H    26.78  27.04  21.06
1 L     1.20   1.41   2.04
2 M     1.23   1.72   2.47
4 R    66.13  51.49  16.62
5 F       --  46.89  22.35
```

Comment: Always great explanations. Thank you so much